# How do I download an entire directory from Dropbox?

Tags: dropbox

Is it possible to download an entire directory and its sub-directories from Dropbox, or do I have to download each file individually?

Comment: Presumably you're talking about from the website? If you just install the software it will sync everything automatically, doesn't it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are accessing Dropbox using a browser, you can select the folder you wish to download by highlighting it, then click the "Download" option on the menu above (see screenshot). Dropbox will then zip the whole folder and let you download it that way.

[image: Download a directory]

Comment: nice... never saw that option -.- thanks from me too Isxek

Comment: the archive is always broken, I don't know why... Files are renamed to a very short name, folders are not in there. missing files..

Comment: @Totty: if you don't have issues downloading stuff from other parts of the Web (e.g., hosting sites like Mediafire & Rapidshare), I would suggest reaching out to Dropbox support.

Answer (score 2):

Dropbox has changed quite a bit since this question was asked in 2010, so here's a more up-to-date answer.

---

**Click the `...` button to the left of your folder, then click `Download` in the newly opened window. You'll then be prompted to save the entire folder as a `.zip` file.**

[image: Downloading folder from Dropbox]